# TypeError: An error occurred while decoding the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, websocket

**GIST**: Server cannot decode _id when request is sent along with korean alphabets.

I'm sending a WebSocket message from my local Live Server page to my EC2 Ubuntu backend server like so:

`websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ event: 'update', body: { _id: '657020a8ba9634238217273', name: "왜", memo: "엥" } }))`

and my server is receiving this message and proceeding to save to DB with this logic:

`await db.collection('datas').updateOne( { _id: new ObjectId(_id) }, { $set: { name, memo } } )`

I'm using MongoDB and this works perfectly fine in local settings,
i've tried updating all environmental versions on EC2,
but **ONLY and ONLY** when I send **KOREAN ALPHABETS** in name and memo, i get the decoding error. This **works perfectly fine with letters, special chars, and numbers**.

**THE ERROR IS CAUGHT IN THE LINE at new ObjectId(_id)**

**additional error info**:
`(function (items){"use strict";if(@isUndefinedOrNull(items))@throwTypeError("The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object.");if(typeof items==="string"||typeof items==="object"&&(@isTypedArrayView(items)||items instanceof @ArrayBuffer||items instanceof SharedArrayBuffer||items instanceof @String))switch(@argumentCount()){case 1:return new @Buffer(items);case 2:return new @Buffer(items,@argument(1));default:return new @Buffer(items,@argument(1),@argument(2))}var arrayLike=@toObject(items,"The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object.");if(!@isJSArray(arrayLike)){const toPrimitive=@tryGetByIdWithWellKnownSymbol(items,"toPrimitive");if(toPrimitive){const primitive=toPrimitive.@call(items,"string");if(typeof primitive==="string")switch(@argumentCount()){case 1:return new @Buffer(primitive);case 2:return new @Buffer(primitive,@argument(1));default:return new @Buffer(primitive,@argument(1),@argument(2))}}if(!("length"in arrayLike)||@isCallable(arrayLike))@throwTypeError("The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object.")}return new @Buffer(@Uint8Array.from(arrayLike).buffer)})`

Above works perfectly fine **EXCEPT** when korean letters are included in the WebSocket message.